# Using jquery to load a page in a div upon document.ready with flask framework

Tags: jquery, python, html

I have the following in the `<script>` section of my `main.html`.

```javascript
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.get("/welcome/", function(res) {
        $("#welcome").html(res);
    });
});
```

In the body of this `main.html`, I have

```html
<div id="welcome"></div>
```

In my flask main python program, I have

```python
@app.route('/welcome/')
def welcome():
    return render_template('welcome.html')
```

The `welcome.html` is fairly simple:

```html
<div><span>Welcome to this site</span></div>
```

This does not render the page welcome.html to the `<div>` section of the site. I understand that there are several responses on stackoverflow that already addressed how to load a page with jquery (e.g. using `load()`); however, I specifically want to use my implementation for legacy reasons. Where did I miss?

Comment: Did you check if there are any errors in the Developer Console of your browser? Did you check that the /welcome/ page works by opening it manually?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I looked at the developer console, it says Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined... However, I am pretty sure I loaded the jquery CDN at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load jquery CDN at the bottom of your page, see if your tag `<script>` is put after this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get("/welcome/",function(res){
            $("#welcome").html(res); 
        }); 
    });
</script>
```